# toString method printing null variables, cant understand why (Java)

Tags: java, tostring

I haven't found any help on here so I'm gonna just ask.

```
public  Ride(String n, int tr, double hr , int nr){
    String name = n;
    int ticketsRequired = tr;
    double heightRequirement = hr;
    int numberOfRiders = nr;
}

public String toString(){

    String info;

    info = this.name + " Requiring " + this.ticketsRequired + 
            " tickets with a height restriction of " +       heightRequirement;

    return info;
}
```

That is in once class, then i try to call it in a main method in another program within my package via this:

```
r1 = new Ride("Death run",0, 5.2, 5);
System.out.println( r1.toString());
```

Which will return this

```
null Requiring 0 tickets with a height restriction of 0.0
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple but this is driving me insane.

Comment: It's nice to have `@Override` there.

Answer (score 13):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your instance variables in your constructor :

```
public Ride(String n, int tr, double hr , int nr){
    name = n;
    ticketsRequired = tr;
    heightRequirement = hr;
    numberOfRiders = nr;
}
```

Using `this` with a field in the constructor is not required here, but it is a good pratice as they are often shadowed by the constructor's parameters (see [using the this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)).

Here's a version using the `this` keyword:

```
public Ride(String n, int tr, double hr , int nr){
    this.name = n;
    this.ticketsRequired = tr;
    this.heightRequirement = hr;
    this.numberOfRiders = nr;
}
```

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning that the values he's getting are the [default values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) - each per its type.

Comment: It's slightly better if he uses "this.<var>" instead of referencing the variables naked like that. Using the "this" keyword will ensure that he doesn't accidentally assign a variable back to itself.

Comment: so why doesn't "this.name" in his toString() give a can't resolve error?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun So he did declare "private String name;" above the constructor?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun That's what I figured. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: how can I get toString to display the variables declared within r1.

Comment: @NolanHodge Did you modify your constructor?

Comment: @ZouZou How should I go about doing this

Comment: @NolanHodge Change it like I said in my answer. Did you understand what was different with what you had?

Comment: @ZouZou Thank you so much, I wasnt aware declaring variable types would shadow them, you have helped me out a lot!

Comment: @NolanHodge Don't forget to accept this answer if it has helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are treating the variables like if they were instance variables, however you have declared them locally inside the constructor. Therefore, once it gets out of the scope you declared them in (the constructor), the value of the `String` object will be null and the value of the int and double variables will be 0 (since it's the default value).

Comment: "their value is null" - No. Only *objects*. `int` for example will be 0, `double` would be 0.0 and so on. See [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: True, I was thinking in the title of the question (method printing NULL VALUES) when I wrote the answer.

Comment: Edit your answer and it'll be perfect :)

Comment: Done. I hadn't thought about editing my answer... I am still a noob here hehe

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you want your class definition:

```
public class Ride
{
  String name;
  int ticketsRequired;
  double heightRequirement;
  int numberOfRiders;

  public  Ride(String n, int tr, double hr , int nr){
    name = n;
    ticketsRequired = tr;
    heightRequirement = hr;
    numberOfRiders = nr;
  }

  public String toString(){

    String info;

    info = this.name + " Requiring " + this.ticketsRequired + 
        " tickets with a height restriction of " + this.heightRequirement;

    return info;
  }
}
```

EDIT: fixed a minor problem in the code snippet

Comment: The Ride (n, tr, hr, nr);
 is inside the Ride() class already

Comment: I'm just showing you how your constructor "should" be, I'm not adding any new methods.